# BarcodeScanning.getClient() Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

When i am trying to run the barcode scan it crashes with the following error, i Even try to upgrade and downgrade all libraries, but no effect happens, Although the standalone sample is working fine, I also view all sort of possibilities to view google issue tracker and others.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.internal.BarcodeScannerImpl com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.internal.zze.zzb(com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScannerOptions)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                    at com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScanning.getClient(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning@@18.1.0:3)
                                                                                                    at pk.caltex.chevron.ScannerActivity.bindAnalyseUseCase(ScannerActivity.kt:180)
                                                                                                    at pk.caltex.chevron.ScannerActivity.bindCameraUseCases(ScannerActivity.kt:128)
                                                                                                    at pk.caltex.chevron.ScannerActivity.access$bindCameraUseCases(ScannerActivity.kt:45)
                                                                                                    at pk.caltex.chevron.ScannerActivity$setupCamera$1.invoke(ScannerActivity.kt:115)
                                                                                                    at pk.caltex.chevron.ScannerActivity$setupCamera$1.invoke(ScannerActivity.kt:112)
                                                                                                    at pk.caltex.chevron.ScannerActivity.setupCamera$lambda$0(ScannerActivity.kt:112)
                                                                                                    at pk.caltex.chevron.ScannerActivity.$r8$lambda$888cEQUj2f0zqrTZxCdbhbRUXAM(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                    at pk.caltex.chevron.ScannerActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onChanged(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
                                                                                                    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:151)
                                                                                                    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:309)
                                                                                                    at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
                                                                                                    at pk.caltex.chevron.CameraXViewModel._get_processCameraProvider_$lambda$0(CameraXViewModel.kt:24)
                                                                                                    at pk.caltex.chevron.CameraXViewModel.$r8$lambda$f983IYe2OCbdRYR-WixR3PHO3jU(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                    at pk.caltex.chevron.CameraXViewModel$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7191)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:499)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
```

Comment: Could you provide more details? e.g., the version you are using, the code snippet to reproduce this.